# Can I write PDF without PDF library in php?

Tags: php, pdf

I want to write users information on **PDF** format. can I write this without **PDF** library, if I can't this please suggest me a pdf library.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php maybe?

Comment: Have you tried searching for _PHP PDF library_? We rather like people to have done some good prior research here `:)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.tcpdf.org/ TCPDF 
http://www.fpdf.org/ FPDF.

Evaluate as per your requirements and integrate in your code.

Comment: both of them are very popular and very easy to integrate.